# В системе не работает комбинация CTRL+SHIFT+Z(Redo)

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Система: ***Linux doox911-PC 5.4.0-42-generic #46~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 10 07:21:24 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux***

Комбинация протестировал в Shtorm, VSCodium и Gedit и в Броузерах. Везде не работает. Сама клавиатура исправна, так как работает верхний регистр и протестировал комбинацию на сторонних сайтах. Перезагружал систему. Результата нет. Что могло произойти? Может кто перехватывает сигнал?

Переустановил систему(Ubuntu 20.04) - проблема осталась. Что могло случиться?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1035114/how-can-i-set-the-shortcut-for-redo-from-ctrlshiftz-to-ctrly

Comment: Первое, что приходит на ум — переключение раскладок на shift-ctrl... то что при этом не работают комбинации — старый баг... для проверки см. `setxkbmap -query`, внимание на `grp:shift_ctrl_toggle` в `options`.

Comment: смените переключение раскладки на капслок

Comment: @BeastWinterwolf делал через `gnome-tweaks`  не помогло.

Comment: @Fat-Zer ничего не понял( Подскажите что погуглить для начала. Или проще систему переустановить.

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica Я видел, но у меня не проблема в настройке. А проблема в том, что просто напросто это не работает. Или я не понял там ответа.

Comment: А может всё-таки Ctrl+Y попробовать?

Comment: Нашел источник проблемы... Оказалось что клавиатура не корректно работает. При том, что при тестах, как я уже писал выше, все нажатия клавиш распознавались. Но ничего, пару часиков потрачу на настройку) Зато новая `Ubuntu`)

Comment: @Qwertiy  это работало, но мне это не удобно.